# Python genfromtext multiple datatypes

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, genfromtxt

I would like to read in a csv file using genfromtxt.
I have six columns that are float, and one column that is a string.

How do I set the datatype so that the float columns will be read in as floats and the string column will be read in as strings?  I tried dtype='void' but that is not working.

Suggestions?

Thanks

.csv file

```
999.9, abc, 34, 78, 12.3
1.3, ghf, 12, 8.4, 23.7
101.7, evf, 89, 2.4, 11.3



x = sys.argv[1]
f = open(x, 'r')
y = np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter = ',', dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', 'S4'), (\
'f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8')])

ionenergy = y[:,0]
units = y[:,1]
```

Error:

```
ionenergy = y[:,0]
IndexError: invalid index
```

I don't get this error when I specify a single data type..

Answer (score 4):

`dtype=None` tells `genfromtxt` to guess the appropriate dtype.

From [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy-genfromtxt):

> dtype: dtype, optional
>
> Data type of the resulting array. **If None, the dtypes will be
>   determined by the contents of each column, individually.**

(my emphasis.)

---

Since your data is comma-separated, be sure to include `delimiter=','` or else `np.genfromtxt` will interpret each column (execpt the last) as including a string character (the comma) and therefore mistakenly assign a string dtype to each of those columns.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.genfromtxt('data', dtype=None, delimiter=',')

print(arr.dtype)
# [('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', 'S4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8')]
```

This shows the names and dtypes of each column. For example, `('f3', <f8)` means the fourth column has name `'f3'` and is of dtype '<i4. The `i` means it is an integer dtype. If you need the third column to be a float dtype then there are a few options.

1. You could manually edit the data by adding a decimal point in the
   third column to force genfromtxt to interpret values in that column
   to be of a float dtype.
2. You could supply the dtype explicitly in the call to genfromtxt

   ```
   arr = np.genfromtxt(
       'data', delimiter=',',
       dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', 'S4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8')])
   ```

---

```
print(arr)
# [(999.9, ' abc', 34, 78.0, 12.3) (1.3, ' ghf', 12, 8.4, 23.7)
#  (101.7, ' evf', 89, 2.4, 11.3)]

print(arr['f2'])
# [34 12 89]
```

---

The error message `IndexError: invalid index` is being generated by the line

```
ionenergy = y[:,0]
```

When you have mixed dtypes, `np.genfromtxt` returns a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). You need to read up on structured arrays because the syntax for accessing columns differs from the syntax used for plain arrays of homogenous dtype.

Instead of `y[:, 0]`, to access the first column of the structured array `y`, use

```
y['f0']
```

Or, better yet, supply the `names` parameter in `np.genfromtxt`, so you can use a more relevant column name, like `y['ionenergy']`:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.genfromtxt(
    'data', delimiter=',', dtype=None,
    names=['ionenergy', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux', 'corge'])

print(arr['ionenergy'])
# [ 999.9    1.3  101.7]
```

Comment: What was the resultant dtype? Was there any text in the columns that should be `float`s? Did you use `names` or `skip_header` to deal with the header (if there was one)?

Comment: I don't have a header.  Using dtype=None, I get an error of an invalid index range when I try to assign each column.  Also, there is not text in a column that should be just float.

Comment: Please post a sample of the text you are parsing with `genfromtxt`.

Comment: Okay, I tried specifying each column, but an still getting an invalid index error.

Comment: Could you post your code and the full traceback error message?

Comment: Okay, it has been added.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
import numpy

ionenergy = y.iloc[:,0]
units = y.iloc[:,1]
```

Comment: Hi @Joye, can you explain what the `.iloc` construction is doing here, and what that has to do with data types?