# load txt file containing string in python as matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a .txt file containing int, string and floats. How can I import this .txt file as a matrix while keeping strings?

Dataset contains:

```
16  disk    11  10.29   4.63    30.22  nan
79  table   11  20.49   60.60   20.22  nan
17  disk    11  22.17   0.71    10.37  nan
```

I used:

```
data=np.loadtxt("/home/Desktop/dataset.txt", delimiter=',')
```

the result is:

```
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)] 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: disk
```

In another try I used:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('/home/Desktop/dataset.txt', delimiter=",")
```

The result is:

```
16.0    nan 11  10.29   4.63    30.22
79.0    nan 11  20.49   60.60   20.22
17.0    nan 11  22.17   0.71    10.37
```

Comment: You might want to use `pandas` package. It supports data frames which can be a mix of different data types.

Comment: I thought you could do this by setting the `dtype` parameter.

Comment: Have you tried `dtype=None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to load values of different types (e.g. str and float) to numpy array.
You could use [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function from pandas package instead:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("/home/Desktop/dataset.txt")
```

Pandas will load data to a DataFrame and you will be able to access columns and row by their names. You could read more about pandas [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)

Comment: *"There is no way to load values of different types (e.g. str and float) to numpy array."*  This is not true.  Mixed types like that can be read into a structured array.  See, for example, this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622997/python-genfromtext-multiple-datatypes